# Automatic timestamp generator plugin on RabbitMQ broker

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I've searched a lot on Google or directly on Stackoverflow and I know that AMQP's timestamp message property must be filled by the producer.

But I want to know if there is some plugin that writes out on this parameter based on the broker's local timestamp automatic when the message is putted on each queue by a topic exchange.

I'm on a situation that neither producer's nor consumer's timestamps are reliable. Only the broker has a trustworthy watch.

I'm not an Erlang programmer but, if there is no known plugin to do that, I need some help. How could I start to write it myself?

I just need to:

Publish some message by someone who doesn't rely on his local timestamp. 
Put this message on each queue mapped on my broker's topic exchange (with it's local timestamp, now I need only this step)
Finally, anyone for whom this message was addressed to is able to get the message and see the exact time this message landed on the broker.

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.3.4, Erlang R16B03, on an Ubuntu's new Amazon AWS machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try [official Plugin Development Guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugin-development.html). Also look through [official](https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html) and [community](https://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins.html) plugins and their sources. In addition you can always googled any other rabbitmq plugins not listed in lists above. Finally, there are [official RabbitMQ mailing list on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) (replaced http://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss).

Comment: Thank you zaq. Sorry for my fault. I did not say that I've read these links I've not found a plugin to do what I need.

Comment: Thank you zaq. Sorry for my fault. I did not say that I've read these links I've not found a plugin to do what I need.
I believe that it's a simple thing to do and maybe someone could have been in the same situation.
Simple thing for someone plainly able to code in Erlang. That's not my case.

Comment: Try to look into plugins sources to get the idea how to write a new one. You may want (in fact, probably, the only way) is to set/modify some timestamp-related custom message header, say, `x-received-timestamp` to current broker timestamp. PS.: alternatively, if it an option for you, you can host some timestamp api to sync your applications timestamp with your master server.